# How to query a DataSets Tables collection with a 'contains or using wildcards for 'TableName' property

Tags: c#, dataset, wildcard

Looking for similar functionality to powerShell's Where-Object

Ex:

```
$dataset.Tables | Where-Object { $_.TableName -like "Shoreline*"}
```

This would return data from the ShorlineEast, ShorelineWest, & ShorelineSouth tables when using PowerShell

Comment: I deleted my answer because it looks like the c# DataSet class doesn't directly support Linq queries among the Tables collection. Before I look for an alternative, can you describe your data source? Are you loading a DataSet from a database directly?

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the `DataSet.Tables` collection to an enumerable of `DataTable` like this:

```
new DataSet().Tables.Cast<DataTable>().Where(t => t.TableName.Contains("whatever"));
```

Then you can stick a where clause on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
dataset.Tables.Add(new DataTable("Shoreline"));
dataset.Tables.Add(new DataTable("Test"));

List<DataTable> tables = (from DataTable datatable in dataset.Tables
                          where datatable.TableName.Contains("Shoreline")
                          select datatable).ToList();
```